# Having trouble getting ddwrt repeater to do more than half work

Tags: router

I did this:

http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Client_Bridged

And it half works. I can ping the client bridged router from my wired network and I can get to the ddwrt admin page on the router via the wireless bridge it made to my main wireless router.

The only problem is, I can't get any of my wireless devices to find the client bridge side of the wireless signal, so it serves no practical purpose.

Maybe I understood it wrong, but I thought it basically functions as an extension of the main wireless router by bridging (via wireless) but still letting other clients (eg. my laptop) still connect to it wirelessly. effectively increasing the physical range of my wireless network. Is this not what it's for?

Comment: Hm... maybe I should be doing this instead.... http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Universal_Wireless_Repeater

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want is a [repeater bridge](http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Bridging#Repeater_Bridge):

> This bridge is like a client bridge, except it adds the functionality of extending the range of your wireless network. The range is extended because, presumably, your secondary router is some distance removed from the main router. In repeater bridge mode, a wireless client can connect to either your main router or your secondary router (repeater bridge).

Follow [these instructions](http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Repeater_Bridge):

> To enable bridge mode between two routers, the primary router must be in AP mode (default) with DHCP Server enabled. The secondary router running DD-WRT v24 will be configured as the Repeater Bridge.

Remember, the physical interface must have the same SSID as the primary wireless router, and you must create a virtual interface with a different SSID.

Comment: where is the setup wiki page for that? That sounds like what I'm looking for.

Comment: @Stu: It's linked above, as "these instructions": http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Repeater_Bridge#Instructions

Comment: worked swimmingly, by the way.